# Why doesn't the variable in this query work to return any values?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using this to search a large database to find tables where the column name I'm searching for exists. Maybe I'm over-complicating this, but I want to be able to search the database by entering a criteria once, and then covering any variations that exist. I have to do this for several hundred column names, and entering all three possibilities over and over again would be painful.

I've tried not using aliases in the **WHERE** part of the query, but I end up getting bounding errors as such:

> THE MULTI-PART IDENTIFIER … COULD NOT BE BOUND

```
DECLARE 
    @searchColumn varchar
SELECT 
    a.name AS TableName, 
    b.name AS ColumnName
FROM sys.columns b
JOIN sys.tables a ON b.object_id = a.object_id
WHERE 
    @searchColumn = 'inst_key'
    and b.name LIKE @searchColumn
            or b.name LIKE concat('%',@searchColumn)
            or b.name LIKE concat('%',@searchColumn,'%')
            or b.name LIKE concat(@searchColumn,'%')
ORDER BY
    a.name asc, b.name asc;
```

I'm hoping to get this query to return a list of all the tables and columns that return a match for the @searchColumn variable.

Comment: This is strange search column always has the value `%inst_key%` but you add `%`?

Comment: @Hogan that was a mistake - I was trying to see if I could get it to work at all, and I left that in there. I've just updated so that it makes more sense. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Since the `'%'` wildcard matches _zero_ or more characters you can simply use `b.name like '%' + @searchColumn + '%'`. No need to try four times. Using `@searchColumn = 'inst_key'` when `@searchColumn` is uninitialized ought to match zero rows. Your use of `and` and `or` isn't likely to be doing what you expect: either the first two conditions are _both_ true or _any_ of the last three.

Comment: You must before assign this variable with SET @searchColumn = 'inst_key' and the you use your query (so you can remove from where this assignment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are declaring a variable and not assigning any value (also not declaring it's length). Change this:

```
DECLARE @searchColumn varchar
```

For

```
DECLARE @searchColumn varchar(100) = 'ValueToSearch' -- Put the searched column partial name here
```

Then you also want to remove the hard-coded value check in your query. There are a few problems with the `WHERE` clause, I'll detail here:

```
WHERE 
    @searchColumn = 'inst_key'
    and b.name LIKE @searchColumn
            or b.name LIKE concat('%',@searchColumn)
            or b.name LIKE concat('%',@searchColumn,'%')
            or b.name LIKE concat(@searchColumn,'%')
```

- You are mixing `AND` and `OR` operators without parenthesis (the engine might not use the precedence you are expecting it to use).
- The first expression will only be true if your variable has value `'inst_key'`, which will always be false since you didn't assign any value (it's `NULL`).
- The `LIKE` special character `%` will match 0 to N characters, so all your 4 `LIKE` expressions can be reduced to `LIKE '%' + @searchColumn + '%'`. If you would like to escape the variable's NULL value, just use `ISNULL(@searchColumn, '')`.

This is the fixed query:

```
DECLARE @searchColumn varchar(100) = 'PartialColumnNameToSearch'

SELECT 
    a.name AS TableName, 
    b.name AS ColumnName
FROM sys.columns b
JOIN sys.tables a ON b.object_id = a.object_id
WHERE 
    b.name LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@searchColumn, '') + '%'
ORDER BY
    a.name asc, b.name asc;
```

If the variable's value is `NULL`, the `LIKE` will result in `'%%'` and it will match all records (except `NULL` values, but no table can have `NULL` as column name).

---

The error message:

> THE MULTI-PART IDENTIFIER … COULD NOT BE BOUND

States that there is an aliased column reference that couldn't be found (or server/database). This isn't the problem for you query so I'm assuming that you edited the SQL you posted after getting this error message.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for explaining what I did wrong instead of just posting the corrected query. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your Query seems to be ok (it works on my machine ;)). The problem might be the variable declaration. Try using VARCHAR(**128**).

Although your WHERE part looks a bit odd,
the following code worked on my SQL Server 2017:

```
DECLARE 
    @searchColumn varchar(128) = 'YOUR_FIELD_NAME_HERE'

SELECT 
    a.name AS TableName, 
    b.name AS ColumnName
FROM sys.columns b
JOIN sys.tables a ON b.object_id = a.object_id
WHERE 
    @searchColumn = 'inst_key'
    and b.name LIKE @searchColumn
            or b.name LIKE concat('%',@searchColumn)
            or b.name LIKE concat('%',@searchColumn,'%')
            or b.name LIKE concat(@searchColumn,'%')
ORDER BY
    a.name asc, b.name asc;
```

**Edit:**

I tried it also on a SQL Server 2012, works like a charm.

**Edit 2:**
Perhaps the following is what you're looking for?

```
DECLARE 
    @searchColumn varchar(128) = 'inst_key'

SELECT 
    a.name AS TableName, 
    b.name AS ColumnName
FROM sys.columns b
JOIN sys.tables a ON b.object_id = a.object_id
WHERE 
    b.name LIKE concat('%',@searchColumn,'%')
ORDER BY
    a.name asc, b.name asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you have an assignment inside a query

I think you want this:

```
WHERE CONTAINS(b.name, 'inst_key')
```

or

```
WHERE CONTAINS(b.name, @searchColumn)
```

---

If you can't use contains then this should be faster --

```
WHERE b.name LIKE ('%' || @searchColumn || '%')
```

will work -- you don't need the 3 versions.  % will match on 0 characters.
Using regex might be faster depending on what platform you are using.

Comment: I don't think I can use CONTAINS because the table doesn't have a full-text index assigned.